# How to get the direct download link inside a page?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('log1.txt', 'w')

url ='http://www.brothersoft.com/tamil-font-513607.html'
pageUrl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageUrl)

for a in soup.select("div.class1.coLeft a[href]"):
    try:
        suburl = ('http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']).encode('utf-8','replace')
        f.write ('http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')
    except:
        print 'cannot read'
        f.write('cannot read:'+'http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')

        pass

    content = urllib.urlopen(suburl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    for a in soup.select("div.Sever1.coLeft a[href]"):
        try:
            suburl2 = ('http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']).encode('utf-8','replace')
            f.write ('http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')
        except:
            print 'cannot read'
            f.write('cannot read:'+'http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')

            pass

        content = urllib.urlopen(suburl2)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
        for a in soup.select("span.p a[href]"):
            try:
                print (a['href']).encode('utf-8','replace')
                f.write ('http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')
            except:
                print 'cannot read'
                f.write('cannot read:'+'http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')

                pass




f.close()
```

When I run it, I get this result:

```
http://www.brothersoft.com/d.php?soft_id=513607&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiles.brotherso
ft.com%2Fphotograph_graphics%2Ffont_tools%2Fkeyman.exe&name=Tamil%20Font
http://ask.brothersoft.com/ask-a-question/?topic=1
http://ask.brothersoft.com/
http://www.brothersoft.com/d.php?soft_id=513607&url=http%3A%2F%2Fusfiles.brother
soft.com%2Fphotograph_graphics%2Ffont_tools%2Fkeyman.exe&name=Tamil%20Font
http://ask.brothersoft.com/ask-a-question/?topic=1
http://ask.brothersoft.com/
```

But what I need is only the direct download link like this:

http://www.brothersoft.com/d.php?soft_id=513607&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiles.brothersoft.com%2Fphotograph_graphics%2Ffont_tools%2Fkeyman.exe&name=Tamil%20Font

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the last block:

```
   for a in soup.select("span.p a[href]"):
        try:
            print (a['href']).encode('utf-8','replace')
            f.write ('http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')
        except:
            print 'cannot read'
            f.write('cannot read:'+'http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')

            pass
```

read the url from the `body`'s `onload` attribute:

```
print soup.find('body')['onload'][10:-2]
```

Comment: Why I got two download links?
http://www.brothersoft.com/d.php?soft_id=513607&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiles.brotherso
ft.com%2Fphotograph_graphics%2Ffont_tools%2Fkeyman.exe&name=Tamil%20Font
http://www.brothersoft.com/d.php?soft_id=513607&url=http%3A%2F%2Fusfiles.brother
soft.com%2Fphotograph_graphics%2Ffont_tools%2Fkeyman.exe&name=Tamil%20Font

Comment: @wanmohdpayed because there are two download mirrows on the second step. You can use `soup.find("div.Sever1.coLeft a[href]")` instead of a loop. Let me know if you have problems with it. Thanks.

Comment: I got this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ext-chermo\Desktop\soup5.py", line 32, in <module>
    content = urllib.urlopen(suburl2)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 179, in open
    fullurl = unwrap(toBytes(fullurl))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 1056, in unwrap
    url = url.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'